# Trying to find maximum value of string in range

Tags: excel, vba

Okay, I have exhausted my feeble knowledge of Excel VBA coding and have not been able to figure out this solution.

I have a single column range of values as part of a table.  The values in this column are groups of sequential strings such as:

```
ABC-001
ABC-002
XYZ-001
EFDDGE-001
ABC-003
XYZ-002
ABC-004
```

What I need to do is assign a value in the next row that is the next value in the whatever the group is.

Example:

1. If the next item is an "ABC" item, I need the value in the column to be `ABC-005`
2. If the next item is a "EFDDGE" item, I need the value in the column to be `EFDDGE-002`
   etc.

The values in the column are in ascending order, by group (ie. `XYZ-005` would never be before `XYZ-003`).

I have been working with the `Range.Find` method, but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

Here is a screen-shot of a sample portion of the table:
(Edit: apparently I can't post images since my "reputation is not a 10 or higher!)

Try to picture this series of columns:

[Next ID] [Item ID] [Description] [Disposition] [Original] [Final] [Weight]

In answer to some of the questions:
Yes, I am indeed trying to add the Item ID in the next available row in the table.

The group portion of the "Item ID" is determined by a VLookup into the "LocationID" table related to the entries in the "Original" or "Final" columns, depending on the "Disposition" value.

As you can see from the above screen shot, I have actually managed to implement a workable method of determining the "Next ID" and then having my VBA userform code copy that value and paste it into the adjacent "Item ID" column.  It works, but it is ugly.  Here is the bloated formula (take a deep breath):

=IF(NOT(ISERROR(CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(G13)),G13,F13),LocationID,2,FALSE),"-",TEXT(SUMPRODUCT((ItemID>VLOOKUP(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(G13)),G13,F13),LocationID,2,FALSE))*(ItemID<=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(G13)),G13,F13),LocationID,2,FALSE),"-999")))+1,"000")))),(CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(G13)),G13,F13),LocationID,2,FALSE),"-",TEXT(SUMPRODUCT((ItemID>VLOOKUP(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(G13)),G13,F13),LocationID,2,FALSE))*(ItemID<=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(G13)),G13,F13),LocationID,2,FALSE),"-999")))+1,"000")))," ")

So ... I have forced this to work, but I was thinking (hoping) that a bit of VBA code in the userform would obviate the need for such a messy method.

BTW, thanks to all of you for even looking at this and for asking pertinent questions and offering possible solutions.
-Bill

Comment: I think you dont need vba for this. this is an automatic function in excel. check this out http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CePq6bnC5oM

Comment: @bto.rdz this doesn't work in E2007 (assuming it doesn't work at all because the data are not strictly numeric).

Comment: How do you know which group to look for?

Comment: each string is 2 parts, group and instance, now you explained you imply want a seeded automatic increment instance number as part two but you did not explain how we are supposed to get the group? is it just a pattern?

Answer (score 3):

> What I need to do is assign a value in the next row

Pretty sure you meant next *column*. Assuming that, try

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1))&TEXT(VALUE(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,3))+1,"000")
```

It looks pretty messy. Let's break it down a little:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)) ; isolates the non-numerical portion
=VALUE(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,3)) ; isolates the numerical portion, converts text to number
```

The remaining code concatenates the two pieces, adding one to the number we isolated, which is converted back to text while ensuring the 3-digit numerical format is preserved.

If you really need VBA we can go there. The technique is the same.

Comment: +1 andy - this will work OK without VALUE function - the +1 in formula serves to implicitly co-erce the text-formatted result of MID to number.....but in any case TEXT function will happily take a text-formatted number and handle it like a real number

Comment: I *think* the question was correct in asking for the next row, he specifically states its data in a single column, it seems he is just trying to fill down the column, row by row.

Comment: On closer look you might be right, in which case my answer fails. If that's the case I'll delete as inappropriate.